# WooCommerce remove billing detail completly

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I really don't want to use billing address concept on WooCommerce completly.

I get money from customer and send product , that's all, no need to make user enter any billing address information.

[iherb](https://au.iherb.com/) site works well without billing address.

If I remove billing address, are there any problem? 
Is there any option like 'Never use billing address' in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any builtin options to hide billing address in WooCommerce because they are WooCommerce default fields. Either you have to create custom code to hide the section using hooks or you have to try a plugin. I have done the same thing but using additional plugin by ThemeHigh.

Answer (score 0):

add code in woccommerce plugin class/wc-countries.php

```
add_filter('wocoommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');

function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields){
unset(#fields['order']['ordercommnets']);
unset ($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
unset ($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
unset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] );
  unset( $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'] );
  unset( $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'] );
  unset( $fields['billing']['billing_city'] );
  unset( $fields['billing']['billing_state'] );
  unset( $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'] );
  unset( $fields['billing']['billing_phone'] );
'''''
''''''
return $fields;
}
```